# implementing In-app-purchase when it's not available

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, adsense, google-developers-console, developer-console

I recently made an android app and was about to set a ***remove ads*** feature through a button click, when I went to Google's developer console and tried to set up a Google's **merchant account** I didn't find my country listed among the available countries

**1/** what should I do ?

**2/** what other solutions do I have ?

**P.S** I realize it is not a "programming" related question, if it's against the community rules, please notify me so I can take it down and guide me where I can find a proper solution